# UDP Multicast architecture considerations

Tags: networking, architecture, routes, multicast

I want to know if there's a downside of architecting a multicast pub-sub like system in the way described below:

### Problem

- There are about 30 applications that need to listen to certain events
- There is 1 server that is receiving events from across the network [let's call it PRODUCER]
- The 30 applications may be interested in one or more of the 30 events

### Solution

- we can assign each topic to a multicast group (defined by an IP in the multicast ip range)
- For each event received by the PRODUCER it multicasts on the relevant channel/group
- The subscribers subscribe to each multicast group/channel that they are interested in

### My questions are

- Is there any overhead in this design as opposed to having each subscriber listening to ALL events and having the PRODUCER send to a single channel - in other words, does sending on multiple channels have a downside?
- For UDP Multicast, my understanding is that a group is defined by an IP address (and not the port). Then what is the relevance of a port in specifying a group/endpoint?

Comment: If you intend for multicasts to be across a network, you will need to enable multicast routing (different than your unicast routing). Also, by default, multicasts have a TTL of 1. Either the multicast routers will need to fix that for you, or your multicast source will need to give the packets a larger TTL.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes I am aware of that but thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @RonMaupin My main concern is with the overhead of sending the same packet on different multicast groups as well as a bit more clarity on what constitutes a group - what role does the port play?

Comment: You aren't sending or receiving any more packets with one group or multiple groups. The purpose of the groups is to reduce overhead on the listeners. If you use a single group, you are forcing every host to process packets in order to determine if they are interested in them, but by using multiple groups, the hosts not interested in the traffic from a group will ignore that traffic.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks - this is what I thought but was looking for confirmation. Also, a group is identified by an IP in the multicast range, right? So what is the relevance of having a port number? Does a port in any way identify a group?

Comment: You are confusing the network layers. A port is a layer-4 address, but an IP address is a layer-3 address. The layers are independent of each other. You need layer-3 to get to the host, and layer-4 to get to the application. The ports allow you to assign traffic to the same IP address (host) to multiple applications. They serve different purposes, like street addresses and room numbers. Without a room number, you could get to the address of a 20-story office building, but where do you go from there? Which office of the 100s of offices in that building?

Comment: @RonMaupin So is it accurate to say that a multicast group is uniquely identified by the multicast address associated with it (irrespective of the port)? Reading this: http://support.mcommstv.com/hc/en-us/articles/202306226-Choosing-multicast-addresses-and-ports it seems that if I have 2 multicast addresses listening to the same port (224.0.0.1:5000 and 224.0.0.2:5000) then the client listening to 224.0.0.1:5000 is actually also going to see the traffic coming on 224.0.0.2:5000 ? Since although the IPs are different but the ports are the same.

Comment: No. A host listening to a multicast group will receive and process all traffic for a multicast group, just like it will receive and process all traffic for its unicast IP address. Whether or not an application is listening on a particular port is a different issue. An application tells layer-4 that it wants to listen to a particular protocol and port (e.g. UDP 5000). Any traffic to that port on the IP address will be sent to that application. Any traffic comes into a protocol/port where no application is listening will be dropped, but the host has wasted resources in order to determine that.

Comment: When layer-2 gets a frame, it looks to see if the MAC address (including multicast MAC address) is meant for it. It rejects it, or it strips the frame and passes the resulting packet to layer-3. At layer-3, IP looks to see if the packet is meant for it. It rejects it, or it strips the packet and passes the resulting datagram up to the layer-4 protocol. The layer-4 protocol looks at the datagram to see the destination port. If there is no application registered for that port, it drops it, otherwise it strips off the layer-4 header and passed the resulting data to the application.

Comment: @RonMaupin Then what about the following scenario 

Host-A: is listening to both mcast addr 239.0.0.1 and 239.0.0.2. 
App-1 on Host-A is listening to 239.0.0.1, port 5000
App-2 on Host-B is listening to 239.0.0.2 port 5000

A sender sends a packet to 239.0.0.1 to port 5000 and another packet to 239.0.0.2 on port 5000.

Based on what you wrote above, it seems both App-1 and App-2 will receive 2 packets each.

Comment: No. Those are two separate IP addresses. A complete address is the IP address, protocol, and port.

Comment: @RonMaupin So this statement taken from this link is incorrect? http://support.mcommstv.com/hc/en-us/articles/202306226-Choosing-multicast-addresses-and-ports

"Choosing a UDP port number for multicast streams is also important.  Even if you use a different multicast IP for each of your streams, we strongly recommend using different UDP port numbers as well. This is because a server and all software running on the server receives ALL multicast traffic on an open port and extra processing is required to filter out the required traffic."

Comment: That would depend on the network stack and OS. From the perspective of how an ideal network stack works, the that would be incorrect, but I don't doubt that for some, or even all, of the real-world implementations that would be true.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, I'll make some experiments and see what I find on my system. Thanks for indulging me! :)